# Rails Devise authentication with email and another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using rails with devise.   On user table I have email and a field record_status.  Record status will contain 'active' or 'deleted'

What do I need to change to authenticate using email and record_status = 'active'.

I have this code in place.

in my user model

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  status = 'active'
  where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :record_status => warden_conditions[:status]).first
end
```

in my initializer devise.rb

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
```

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a initializers for devise its file path is `config/initializers/devise.rb` ruffly on line 37 you should see

```
# config.authentication_keys = [:email]
```

now you can update this to be

```
config.authentication_keys = [:email, :other_field]
```

> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
>    Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
>    just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
>    authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
>    parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
>    session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
>    You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
>    or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.